# VS2013 auto-indents closing bracket on new line, why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I cannot seem to find a way to disable the closing bracket to be auto-indented with all the other args. Example (note the spaces in front of closing bracket)

```
func(
  arg1,
  arg2
  )
```

I want to have it aligned with the function call.

```
func(
  arg1,
  arg2
)
```

But I cannot find the setting in VS formatting options. I am pretty sure my previous VS instances did not have this auto-setting. Now, when I finish typing arg2 and press ENTER, it auto aligns me to the wrong spot.

EDIT: All autoformatting is disabled and tried pretty much all in Formatting options. Maybe the issue is with extensions? I am using Resharper.

Comment: Since I use the German Version of Visual Studio, I guess a screenshot would be not very helpful. But just go to Options -> Text-Editor -> C# -> Formatting and then select the third Entry in the 'Formatting' tree. Then deselect the second entry in the right side of the window. No idea how it's named in English. But you will see the effect in the preview.

Comment: @Mathew "Automatically format on paste" is the third option there. The first two are "Automatically format completed statement on ;" and "Automatically format completed block on }".

Comment: I have these three disabled, that is what had me confused. Maybe the problem is because I am using Resharper?

Comment: ReSharper has a bazillion formatting options. Just click Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style.

Comment: No idea about ReSharper, since I never got to work with it. It seems that the german and english entries aren't exactly the same though. So I'm afraid I can't help you. The entry I meant would translate to something like "Intend Opening and closing brackets"

Comment: I don't think "bracket" means what you thikn it means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the answer, the reason why VS formatting options did not take effect was because the formatting options from ReSharper took precedence.

The setting is in Resharper -> Editor -> Editor Behavior
"Auto-format on closing brace"
"Auto-format on semicolon"
"Auto-insert closing brace"